# Why is the static_cast conversion invalid?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, static-cast

I encountered a problem:

```
int main() {
    const void* p = NULL;
    const int** pp = static_cast<const int**>(p); // E0171 invalid type conversion (1)
    int* const* ppp = static_cast<int* const*>(p); // No error  (2)
}
```

Why is the conversion (1) here invalid, while the (2) is allowed?

Comment: Because `const int**` is `int const**`, int `int* const*`: if you attempt to use this as a target of `void const*`, you are casting away const-ness of the pointee! To preserve const-ness, you need to make the pointee `const`. The pointee is the type you get when stripping away the outermost pointer.

Comment: `static_cast` in C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `static_cast` is not allowed to remove `const` from the pointed-to type, only `const_cast` is allowed to do that.

**(1)** In the conversion:

```cpp
// pointer to CONST void     pointer to MUTABLE pointer to const int
   const void *          ->  const int **
```

We are removing the const qualification from the pointed-to type.
Without using `const_cast` to remove constness completely (which is probably not correct), we need to do:

```cpp
// pointer to CONST void     pointer to CONST pointer to const int
   const void *          ->  const int * const *

// in code:
auto pp = static_cast<const int * const *>(p);
```

**(2)** The other conversion:

```cpp
// pointer to CONST void     pointer to CONST pointer to int
   const void *          ->  int * const *
```

... is perfectly fine, because we are  preserving the const-ness of what was pointed to.

---

*Note: if you are having trouble with figuring out C/C++ type syntax, I recommend using [cdecl+](https://cdecl.plus/?q=const%20int%20*%20const%20*), an online tool which converts syntax to English prose.*

Answer (score 0):

In conversion (1), p is a const void* pointer, which means it points to a constant object of unknown type. You are trying to pass this pointer to a const int** pointer, which is a pointer to a pointer to a constant integer. However, this allows you to modify the constant integer via the const int** pointer, which is not allowed and violates object constancy.

In contrast, in conversion (2), you are trying to cast the same const void* pointer to a const* int* pointer that is a pointer to a constant pointer to a non-const integer. This is allowed because the pointer itself is constant, but the integer it points to is not. Therefore, you can safely cast p to this type without violating object stability.